# jQuery select2 genemuFormBundle issue

Tags: forms, jquery, symfony-2.1, jquery-select2

I am trying to implement ajax call using select2 as per this example:
https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/jquery/select2/ajax.md

Here is my code:

```
        var $configs = {{ configs|json_encode|raw }};

    $field = $('#{{ id }}');
    $configs = $.extend($configs, {
        ajax: {
            id: function (friend) { return friend.username; },
            url: $field.data('url'),
            data: function (term, page) {
                return { q: term, page_limit: 10, page: page };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                var more = (page * 10) < data.total;
                return { results: data, more: more };
            }
        },
        formatResult: function (friend) {
            var markup = "<div class='friend-results-box'>";
            if (friend.avatar !== undefined) {
            markup += "<img width='60' height='75' src='" + friend.avatar + "'/>";
            }
            markup += "<h5>" + friend.username + "</h5>";
            markup += "<div class'clearfix'></div>";
            markup += "</div>";
            return markup;
        },
        initSelection : function (element, callback) {
            var elementText = $(element).attr('data-init-text'); // ?
            callback({"term":elementText});
        },
        formatSelection: function (friend) { return friend.username; },
        escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; },
        dropdownCssClass: "dropdown-friends"
    });

    $field.select2($configs);
```

Now my issues are:

1. Value is being filled in with ID when my intention is to have a
   value    taken from json defined there as friend.username
2. After page reload initial value is not being presented on the screen
   (as value is being set to ID) and select2 does not pick it up

Any tips or help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your initSelection function has this:  callback({"term":elementText});

by default Select2 expects {id:"someid", text:"sometext"}

Best to start simple with no formatting of any kind, get that working then make it look like you want.